# REGEX - Insert space after every 4 characters, and a line break after every 40 characters

Tags: regex, insert

I have a huge string (22000+ characters) of encoded text. The code is consisted of digits [0-9] and lower case letters [a-z]. I need a regular expression to insert a space after every 4 characters, and one to insert a line break [\n] after every fourty characters. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a job for a regex.

Comment: @Cfreak why not? And if not, any ideas how could I get it done?

Comment: Because regex is for extract information from a string. This is strictly manipulation. What language are you trying to perform this in?

Comment: It's not a programming language, it's just a string of plain text.

Comment: No, what programming language are you going to do the string manipulation in? This is really not a job for regular expressions, I want to retag your question.

Comment: To be honest, I really don't need to do it with regex, as long as it's done. Any other ideas then?

Comment: @DavidB I'm not sure if I understand you. I have a text file open in my text editor. The file contains nothing but a long line of digits and letters. What I am trying to do is use my text editor's Find&Replace to insert a space after every 4 characters. I thought regex would help me with that, since I've been doing something similar before.

Comment: No, that isn't how regex works. Regex can be used with Find/Replace tools to find certain patterns in strings, or extract information from certain patterns. Something like this could probably be done in an editor like `vi` or in a programming language like `Python` or `Perl`.

Comment: If you need insert a character at particular points, like every 4 characters you could simply loop through each character or you could split the string or you could use substr. Most languages have a variety of ways to do such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a regexp in itself doesn't insert a space, so I'll assume you have some command in whatever language you're using that inserts based on finding a regexp.

So, finding 4 characters and finding 40 characters: that's not pretty in general regular expressions (unless your particular implementation has nice ways to express numbers). For finding 4 characters, use

```
....
```

Because typical regexp finders use maximal munch, then from the end of one regexp, search forward and maximally munch again, that'll chunk your string into 4 character pieces. The ugly part is that in standard regular expressions, you'll have to use

```
........................................
```

to find chuncks of 40 characters, although I'll note that if you run your 4 character one first, you'll have to run

```
..................................................
```

or

```
.... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....
```

to account for the spaces you've already put in.

The period finds any characters, but given that you're only using [0-9|a-z], you could use that regexp in place of each period if you need to ensure nothing else slipped in, I was just avoiding making it even more gross.

As you may be noting, regexp have some limitations. Take a look at the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) to really get into their theoretical limitations.

Comment: neat. Did the job perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: instead of `..........` it is possible to use `.{10}` (any character, repeated 10 times)

Comment: In most newer regexp implementations, yes, but since the OP was general, I gave an answer that'll work regardless of his language and implementation.

Comment: I'll try to clarify a bit. I'm sorry for my inprecise terminology. I guess I should have explained that I have a string of text open in my editor and that I want to do this task using the editor's Find&Replace which supports regex. I've managed to do it thanks to Akroy's method, using '(....)' for find and '\1 ' for replace. Then I've repeated the same thing with 40 dots for find and '\1\n' for replace.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't intend that as an attack on you! :) Glad it worked well!

Comment: Regexps with `String.replace` can insert spaces

Answer (score 8):

Many people would prefer to do this with a for loop and string concatenation, but I hate those `substring` calls. I am really against using regexes when they aren't the right tool for the job (parsing HTML), but I think it'd pretty easy to work with in this case.

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rafgp/2/)

Let's say you have the string

```
var str = "aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffgggghhhhiiiijjjjkkkkllllmmmmnnnnoooo";
```

And you want to insert a space after every four characters, and a newline after 40 characters, you could use the following code

```
str.replace(/.{4}g/, function (value, index){
    return value + (index % 40 == 36? '\n' : ' ');
});
```

Note that this wouldn't work if the newline(40) index wasn't a multiple of the space index(4)

I abstracted this in a project, here's a simple way to do it

```
/**
 * Adds padding and newlines into a string without whitespace
 * @param {str} str The str to be modified (any whitespace will be stripped)
 * @param {int} spaceEvery number of characters before inserting a space
 * @param {int} wrapeEvery number of spaces before using a newline instead 
 * return {string} The replaced string
 */
function addPadding(str, spaceEvery, wrapEvery) {
    var regex = new RegExp(".{"+spaceEvery+"}", "g"); 
    // Add space every {spaceEvery} chars, newline after {wrapEvery} spaces
    return str.replace(/[\n\s]/g, '').replace(regex, function(value, index) {
        // The index is the group that just finished
        var newlineIndex = spaceEvery * (wrapEvery - 1);
        return value + ((index % (spaceEvery * wrapEvery) === newlineIndex) ? '\n' : ' ');
    });
}
```