# Create a field to Credit Card Form

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a payment form and i want that when the user type his credit card number every 4 characters automatically inserts a space.
I tried with data-mask but i don't work and on web i don't find what i searched.
How can i get this result in the most simple way?

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="numero_carta">Numero Carta</label>
          <div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="9999-9999-9999-9999" data-mask-placeholder="*">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
          </div>
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Are you getting an error?  What is it *actually* doing?  Are you including the mask script?

Comment: Regex. This answer covers the space after 4 digits : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057957/regex-insert-space-after-every-4-characters-and-a-line-break-after-every-40-c